# How to make changing minor-mode lighter in modeline?

Tags: minor-mode

In `minor-mode-alist` documentation it is described that lighter can be a lisp expression that is evaluated to get text used in the display of minor mode in mode line. It has the form of (:eval ...)

Given a function that makes such a string upon evaluation, for example, called `compose-mode-line` (no parameters), how minor-mode's lighter can be set to results of evaluation of that function?

Comment: Here is a link to a thread that contains other ways to change the lighter, which do not use `compose-mode-line`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23944621/2112489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
(define-minor-mode ...
  :lighter (:eval (compose-mode-line))
  ...)
```

Note that this will re-compute `(compose-mode-line)` *very* frequently (after every key press, typically), so make sure it does not perform longish or blocking computations.

Comment: i have a branching on a symbol equality there, which is, i believe, cheap enough.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's very cheap.